# Redux Form: Conditional form validations with multiple submit buttons

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-form

[image]

I am using Redux forms with multiple submit buttons along with redux-form `<Field />`. I need to control the validation of these fields based on click of these buttons. For ex. I need to set a flag to True/False based on click of these buttons so that I can conditionally validate my fields like below:

```
        <Field
          name="date"
          component={DateFormField}
          validate={isSaveDraft && [validateRequiredText]}
          floatingLabelText="Date"
          fullWidth
          helpText="blablabla"
        />
        <Field
          name="title"
          component={TextFormField}
          normalizeOnBlur={normalizeTextOnBlur}
          validate={!isSaveDraft && [validateRequiredText]}
          floatingLabelText="Project title"
          fullWidth
          helpText="blablabla"
        />
```

As you can see from above code, I'm conditionally validating my fields with **validate={isSaveDraft && [validateRequiredText]}** and **validate={!isSaveDraft && [validateRequiredText]}**

Here are my two submit buttons:

```
      <RaisedButton
        label={submitting ? 'Saving Draft...' : 'Save Draft'}
        type="button"
        onClick={handleSubmit(values => onSubmit())}
        disabled={submitting}
        primary
      />
    <RaisedButton
      label={submitting ? 'Submitting Brief...' : 'Submit Brief'}
      type="button"
      onClick={handleSubmit(values => onSubmit())}
      disabled={submitting}
      primary
    />
```

However, I'm not able to achieve it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of headaches and head scratching, I've finally found the solution without making things look ugly. Thanks to a fellow developer for this solution. Original idea was to set a flag on click of the button and conditionally validate the fields. (PS: I'm using Field Level Validations). However, the issue was that the validations are being executed BEFORE the flag setting as the onClick handler wouldn't fire before all the validations are fixed and that logic is buried deep inside redux-forms (perks of unnecessarily overcomplicating simple things by using a library).

Here is the solution:

**submit handler**

```
handleSubmit() {
    const { bookingCreate, modalShow, navigateTo } = this.props;
    const { isDraftAction } = this.state; // my flag

    // create record!
    return bookingCreate(isDraftAction)
      .then(responsePayload => {
        ...
      })
      .catch(handleSubmissionError);
 }
```

`isDraftAction` is the flag which is set `(in local state)` when the action is called on `onClick` of both buttons.

**My conditional Field level validations**

```
    <Field
      name="date"
      component={DateFormField}
      validate={isDraftAction && [validateRequiredText]}
      fullWidth
      helpText="blablabla"
    />
    <Field
      name="title"
      component={TextFormField}
      normalizeOnBlur={normalizeTextOnBlur}
      validate={!isDraftAction && [validateRequiredText]}
      fullWidth
      helpText="blablabla"
    />
```

**My 2 buttons for SAVE RECORD and SUBMIT RECORD.**

```
  const submit = handleSubmit(values => onSubmit()); // this is redux-form's submit handler which will in-turn call my own submit handler defined above. (That's where the library hides all the logic and makes developer helpless)

  <RaisedButton
    label={submitting && isDraft ? 'Saving Draft...' : 'Save Draft'}
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
      this.props.dispatchAction({ draftAction: true }).then(() => {
        submit();
      });
    }}
    disabled={submitting}
    primary
  />
  <RaisedButton
    label={submitting && !isDraft ? 'Submitting Brief...' : 'Submit Brief'}
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
      this.props.dispatchAction({ draftAction: false }).then(() => {
        submit();
      });
    }}
    disabled={submitting}
    primary
  />
```

`dispatchAction()` is my action function which will FIRST set the flag to true/false THEN call redux-forms inbuilt submit handler. Also, I've extracted the redux-form's submit handler as it is above only for more clarity.

**dispatchAction()**

```
     dispatchAction={({ draftAction }) =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
          this.setState({ isDraftAction: draftAction }, resolve);
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a state variable as **isSaveDraft** and set it default to **false**
Add **onClick** action of button to set **state.isSaveDraft = true**

Comment: My onClick function is firing AFTER the field validations.

Answer (score 0):

`validate={(isSaveDraft && [validateRequiredText]}` will not work since `validate` expects a function all the time. Also, field level validation happens onTouch, or onBlur etc. which is way too early as you won't know which button will be clicked.

What you need to do is use a extra flag prop to hold which button was clicked and then use that in the form level validation.

So your Fields will look like this (no more Field level validation):

```
<Field
    name="date"
    component={DateFormField}
    floatingLabelText="Date"
    fullWidth
    helpText="blablabla"
/>
...
<RaisedButton
    label={submitting ? 'Saving Draft...' : 'Save Draft'}
    onMouseDown={() => this.setDraftFlag(true)}        
    ...
/>
<RaisedButton
    label={submitting ? 'Submitting Brief...' : 'Submit Brief'}
    onMouseDown={() => this.setDraftFlag(false)}        
    ...
/>
```

I'm using `onMouseDown` to capture the flag since you're already using `onClick` for submitting the form. Besides, we need to do the validation before submit anyway.

And then in your form's `validate` (based on [SyncValidation example](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/syncvalidation/))

```
const validate = values => {
    const errors = {}
    const {isDraft, ...rest} = values

    if(isDraft) {
        // draft validations
    } else {
        // other validations
    }
    return errors
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm', // a unique identifier for this form
    validate, // <--- validation function given to redux-form
})(MyForm)
```

`setDraftFlag` can be an [action](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/) or you can make it part of your Form component like so (I find this easier since you already get `change` bound to your form):

```
setDraftFlag(value) {
    this.props.change('isDraft', value));
}
```

Comment: `validate={(isSaveDraft && [validateRequiredText]} will not work since validate expects a function all the time.`
This is working fine. validateRequiredText is a function and isSaveDraft is a boolean.

Comment: `I'm using onMouseDown...` 
This will fail if user is using keyboard. so it will be an accessibility issue.

Comment: Add another handler for keyboard.

Comment: By the way, `onClick` is also a mouse only event.

Comment: But if you ask me, having 2 buttons, and not a single `submit` is a bad design and if you care for accessibility so much, then it's a terrible design. I'd simply change "Save as Draft" into a checkbox and have only one Submit button. Your form validation becomes simpler, accessibility score goes up and everyone wins.

Comment: hmm I think it's only natural to have both save and submit buttons. Any other way affects the user experience. Anyway, thanks for the help. I've figured out an elegant solution (although certainly not better than using plain javascript forms).