# How to submit invalid form in redux-form? And is it even possible?

Tags: redux-form

I have a `form` and 2 submit flows: *draft* and *detailed*.

There is no validation for submitting the draft.

Some of the fields are required for detailed submitting. One of them is "description".

#### Invalid form:

[image: invalid form]

#### Valid form:

[image: valid form]
Validation works properly and "description" field gets marked as "invalid" if empty:

```
<Field
  component="textarea"
  name="description"
  maxLength={2048}
  validate={[required()]}
  label={<FormattedMessage id={messageIds['entity.ticket.field.description']} />}
/>
```

But at the same time, I can't submit this form as "draft" when the description is empty.

Shortened code:

```js
function TicketFormComponent(props: AllProps) {
  const handleDraftTicketSubmit = props.handleSubmit((values) => {
    props.onTicketCreate({
      ...values,
      status: 'Draft',
    });
  });

  const handleActiveTicketSubmit = props.handleSubmit((values) => {
    props.onTicketCreate({
      ...values,
      status: 'Open',
    });
  });

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleActiveTicketSubmit}>
      <Field
        component={TextInput}
        name="subject"
        maxLength={255}
        label={<FormattedMessage id={messageIds['entity.ticket.field.subject']} />}
      />

      <h3><FormattedMessage id={messageIds['entity.ticket.field.description']} /></h3>
      <Field
        component="textarea"
        name="description"
        maxLength={2048}
        validate={[required()]}
        label={<FormattedMessage id={messageIds['entity.ticket.field.description']} />}
      />

      <Button
        data-aqa="submitDraftTicket"
        disabled={props.submitting || !props.initialValues.selectedTopic}
        onClick={handleDraftTicketSubmit}
        className={props.classes.saveDraftButton}
      >
        <FormattedMessage id={messageIds['entity.ticket.field.saveAsDraft']} />
      </Button>

      <Button
        data-aqa="submitActiveTicket"
        disabled={props.submitting || props.invalid}
        onClick={handleActiveTicketSubmit}
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
      >
        <FormattedMessage id={messageIds['entity.ticket.field.createNewTicket']} />
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

#### Expected result:

Form values are submitted with "Draft" status further through Redux flow

#### Actual result:

form values are not submitted, instead, I get 2 redux actions:

1. `{ type: '@@redux-form/TOUCH' }`
2. `{ type: '@@redux-form/SET_SUBMIT_FAILED', error: true }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing two possibles approaches:

#### 1. Remove `Field` level validation (`validate={[required()]}`) and validate the Form with [SyncValidation](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/syncvalidation/):

```js
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  const {isDraft, ...rest} = values

  if(isDraft) {
      // draft validations
  } else {
      // other validations
  }
  return errors
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate, // <--- validation function given to redux-form
})(MyForm)
```

#### 2. Add the `Field` validation conditionally:

```js
<Field
  name="description"
  validate={!isDraft && [required()]}
/>
```

But here you should change your submission flow. Rather than submitting the Form on 'Save draft' or 'Create ticket' buttons, you have to set a state `isDraft` variable firstly and later submit the form.

Otherwise, submitting the Form on a button click, the conditional `Field` validation won't be applied, because the `Form` will be already submitted.

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732696/redux-form-conditional-form-validations-with-multiple-submit-buttons), the use-case is very similar to yours. So you can take inspiration of it too.

Comment: I managed it in a 3rd way if it would be useful for someone in the future:   
1. "Submit active" indeed submits the form, while "Submit draft" just triggers a "SUBMIT_DRAFT" action.   
2. In my saga on "SUBMIT_DRAFT" action, I use formValueSelector provided by redux-form to retrieve form values. Here I can use "getFormSyncErrors" selector as well to detect whether the form is valid.   
3. If the form is valid I send its data further or show warning otherwise.   
BUT it seems @jordan-enev 's approach is much nicer, it is more SOLID-like with view and validation separated.